# Using backbone.js with xml as the datasource

Tags: xml, mobile, backbone.js, storage, local

I am working on this app -> http://mc-mobile-app.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html. The datasource it is using is local storage.

So the problem is that all posts are only accessible to me. I was considering using a database but made up mind to keep it simple. Is there anyway to make them public using XML?

For instance, I would have one XML file on the server and I would be able to store, read and edit data on that XML file from my app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the annoying answer, but I hope it is better than not answering at all.

Keeping it simple is doing things similar and familiar, not inventing the wheel. 
In practice it will be simple because you'll have the support of modern frameworks. And keeping it simple for the next guy that comes to see your code (will probably be you in a couple of month).

Here is my proposal for a simple and fast solution:

Use node.js + express.js + mongodb for your backend. It will allow you to store models from backbone.js in  json representation (easily binded to xml). You will not need a schema and your code will be readable and extensible.

Again, sorry for not answering your real question, but this is just an example why you should use the path people has already taken